# Loading a texture from assets folder for OpenGL

Tags: java, android, opengl-es

I know there are many questions relating to this question, but few appear to be for openGL.

I'm trying to load some PNG files from the assets folder into a Bitmap, but for some reason the returned Bitmap is null which in turn throws a NullPointerException here:

```
GLUtils.texImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bitmap, 0);
```

The code I am using to load the image from the assets folder:

```
public static Bitmap getBitmapFromAsset(AssetManager mgr, String path)
{
    InputStream is = null;
    Bitmap bitmap = null;
    try {
        is = mgr.open(path);
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inScaled = false;
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is, null, options);
    }
    catch (final IOException e)
    {
        bitmap = null;
        Log.e(TAG, "FAILED TO get getBitmapFromAsset: " + e.getMessage());
    }
    finally
    {
       if (is != null)
       {
            try 
            {
                 is.close();
            } 
            catch (IOException ignored) 
            {
            }
        }
    }

    return bitmap;
}
```

I've tried it a few different ways, e.g without the BitmapFactory.Options, but no matter what I am getting the NullPointerException, so I'm guessing there's another procedure I should be doing.

P.S.  I can load them from the res/raw folder, but I can't have subdirectories to organise my assets.

Comment: Which part is failing? The `open()` method on the `AssetManager`, or the `decodeStream()`? You should be able to tell by stepping through it in a debugger.

Comment: I just separated the calls and it's definitely the open() call that's failing.  String path assumes Android will start looking from the assets folder.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I just realised that my assets folder was under the res folder for some reason.  I just put it under the main folder app/main/assets and it's working.
*blushes